# N Level Map, Need to place map inside map

Tags: java, dictionary

Need a dynamic data structure, which may be similar to a MAP(Java.util.Map), wchich is capable of storing, String and Object. And that Object may again need to store another map, which can store, String and Object.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the requester is looking for something like the below:

```
class MultilevelMap<K,V> extends HashMap<List<K>,V> {
    @SafeVarargs
    public final put(V value, K keys...) {
        put(makeKey(keys), value);
    }
    @SafeVarargs
    public final V get(K keys...) {
        return get(makeKey(keys));
    }
    // The remainder of this class is left as a tedious exercise for the reader
    private List<K> makeKey(K[] keys) {
        List<K> key = new ArrayList<K>(keys.size);
        for(K k: keys) {
            key.add(k);
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

A Trie, as far as I understand it is similar, but opposite. It presents an interface of `Map<S,V>`, but internally is implemented as a variable-depth `Map<K,Map<K, ... V>>` where `K` are consecutive affixes of `S`, such that if you concatenate all of the `K`s between the top of the tree and `V`, you get the `S` you used as the key. The above presents an interface of (very approximately) `Map<K,K, ... , V>`, but internally is `Map<List<K>, V>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest maps (and other containers) to arbitrary depth. This puts a Map in another Map in another ... to a total depth of 10:

```
private Map<String, Object> nest(int levelsLeft, Map<String, Object> parent) {
     if (levelsLeft > 0) {
        parent.put("key" + levelsLeft, 
           nest(levelsLeft - 1, new HashMap<String, Object>()));
     }
     return parent;
}

// from somewhere else
Map<String, Object> nested = nest(10, new Map<String, Object>());
((Map<String, Object>)nested.get("key10")).get("key9"); // goes all the way down to "key1"
```

Note that the price for declaring a `Map<String, Object>` is that, whenever you access something via `get()`, you need to cast it to whatever it actually is to be able to use it as something more specific than an `Object`.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why this does not answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you either need a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) or a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: I don't really see why multimaps are more nested than normal maps, or what tries have to offer here... (note - I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: because Tries are essentially nested maps. e.g. a String trie is `Map[String, Map[String, Map[...]]]`. Whoever down-voted this needs to read their undergraduate data structures book again.